# Transferring categorical means to a new table

Tags: r, histogram, mean, categories

I'm fairly new to **R**, but I've tackled much larger challenges than my current problem, which makes it particularly frustrating. I searched the forums and found some related topics, but none would do the trick for this situation.

I've got a dataset with 184 observations of 14 variables:

```
> head(diving)
   tagID ddmmyy Hour.GMT. Hour.Local.  X0  X3 X10  X20  X50 X100 X150 X200 X300 X400
1 122097 250912         0           9 0.0 0.0 0.3 12.0 15.3 59.6 12.8  0.0    0    0
2 122097 260912         0           9 0.0 2.4 6.9  5.5 13.7 66.5  5.0  0.0    0    0
3 122097 260912         6          15 0.0 1.9 3.6  4.1 12.7 39.3 34.6  3.8    0    0
4 122097 260912        12          21 0.0 0.2 5.5  8.0 18.1 61.4  6.7  0.0    0    0
5 122097 280912         6          15 2.4 9.3 6.0  3.4  7.6 21.1 50.3  0.0    0    0
6 122097 290912        18           3 0.0 0.2 1.6  6.4 41.4 50.4  0.0  0.0    0    0
```

This is tagging data, with each date having one or more 6-hour time bins (not a continuous dataset due to transmission interruptions). In each 6-hour bin, the depths to which the animal dived are broken down, by %, into 10 bins. So X0 = % of time spent between 0-3m, X3= % of time spent between 3-10m, and so on.

What I want to do for starters is take the mean % time spent in each depth bin and plot it. To start, I did the following:

```
avg0<-mean(diving$X0)
avg3<-mean(diving$X3)
avg10<-mean(diving$X10)
avg20<-mean(diving$X20)
avg50<-mean(diving$X50)
avg100<-mean(diving$X100)
avg150<-mean(diving$X150)
avg200<-mean(diving$X200)
avg300<-mean(diving$X300)
avg400<-mean(diving$X400)
```

At this point, I wasn't sure how to then plot the resulting means, so I made them a list:

```
divingmeans<-list(avg0, avg3, avg10, avg20, avg50, avg100, avg150, avg200, avg300, avg400)
```

boxplot(divingmeans) sort of works, providing 1:10 on the X axis and the % 0-30 on the y axis. However, I would prefer a histogram, as well as the x-axis providing categorical bin names (e.g. avg3 or X3), rather than just a rank 1:10.

hist() and plot() provide the following:

```
> plot(divingmeans)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
> hist(divingmeans)
Error in hist.default(divingmeans) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I've also tried:

```
> df<-as.data.frame(divingmeans)
> df
  X3.33097826086957 X3.29945652173913 X8.85760869565217 X17.6461956521739 X30.2614130434783
1          3.330978          3.299457          8.857609           17.6462          30.26141
  X29.3565217391304 X6.44510869565217 X0.664130434782609 X0.135869565217391 X0.0016304347826087
1          29.35652          6.445109          0.6641304          0.1358696         0.001630435
```

and

```
> df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(divingmeans), nrow=10, byrow=T))
> df
   matrix.unlist.divingmeans...nrow...10..byrow...T.
1                                        3.330978261
2                                        3.299456522
3                                        8.857608696
4                                       17.646195652
5                                       30.261413043
6                                       29.356521739
7                                        6.445108696
8                                        0.664130435
9                                        0.135869565
10                                       0.001630435
```

neither of which provide the sort of table I'm looking for.

I know there must be a really basic solution for converting this into an appropriate table, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I'd like to be able to make a basic histogram showing the % of time spent in each diving bin, on average. It seems the best format for the data to be in for this purpose would be a table with two columns: col1=bin (category; e.g. avg50), and col2=% (numeric; mean % time spent in that category).

You'll also notice that the data is broken up into different timing bins; eventually I'd like to be able to separate out the data by time of day, to see if, for example, the average diving depths shift between day/night, and so on. I figure that once I have this initial bit of code worked out, I can then do the same by time-of-day by selecting, for example `X0[which(Hour.GMT.=="6")]`. Tips on this would also be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you like to plot them?

```
# grab the means of each column
diving.means <- colMeans(diving[, -(1:5)])


# plot it
plot(diving.means)

# boxplot
boxplot(diving.means)
```

If youd like to grab the lower bound to intervals from the column names, siply strip away the X

```
lowerIntervalBound <- gsub("X", "", names(diving)[-(1:5)])

# you can convert these to numeric and plot against them 
lowInts <- as.numeric(lowerIntervalBound)
plot(x=lowInts, y=diving.means)

# ... or taking log
plot(x=log(lowInts), y=diving.means)

# ... or as factors (similar to basic plot)
plot(x=factor(lowInts), y=diving.means)
```

instead of putting the diving means in a `list`, try putting them in a `vector` (using `c`).

If you want to combine it into a data.frame:

```
data.frame(lowInts, diving.means)

# or adding a row id if needed. 
data.frame(rowid=seq(along=diving.means), lowInts, diving.means)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys! This one seemed to do the trick in a pretty straightforward way.  I was then able to easily break it down by time-of-day bin with the [which()] command. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find it far easier to deal with the data in long format.

You can `reshape` using `reshape`. I will use data.table to show how to easily calculate the means by group.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(diving)

DTlong <- reshape(DT, varying = list(5:14), direction = 'long', 
  times = c(0,3,10,20,50,100,150,200,300,400), 
  v.names = 'time.spent', timevar = 'hours')

timeByHours <- DTlong[,list(mean.time = mean(time.spent)),by=hours]

# you can then plot the two column data.table

plot(timeByHours, type = 'l')
```

[image]

You can now analyse by any combination of date / hour / time at depth